# Is there a universal way to test the Access Control List of a folder and its children in PowerShell, independently of inheritance?

Tags: powershell, access-control, directory-security, access-control-list

In PowerShell, I can define a [.NET Directory Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.directorysecurity?view=net-8.0) object and give it different rules:

```
$acl = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity
$acl.AddAccessRule($rule_a)
$acl.AddAccessRule($rule_b)
...
```

Now depending of the [Access Rule Protection settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.objectsecurity.setaccessruleprotection?view=net-8.0), those settings in the .Net Directory Security object `$acl` could be inherited to the child items of the folder or not. The inheritance rules can be changed like this:

```
$acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($true, $true) # could also be ($false, $false) or a different setting...
```

After `$acl` has been defined as needed, it gets applied to a folder:

```
Set-Acl $folder $acl
```

---

Now I want to test if the settings in `$acl` have been applied correctly to `$folder`. My expected settings are simply what I defined before in `$acl`:

```
$expectedAclSettings = $acl
```

I can get the [Access Control Lists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/access-control-lists) of a folder and all its child items recursively like this to get the actual acl settings:

```
$folderAndChildren = @(Get-Item -Path $folder) + @(Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -Recurse)
$actualAclSettings = ($folderAndChildren | Get-Acl)
```

Now my question is:

**Is there an easy way (like a one-liner) to compare `$expectedAclSettings` and `$actualAclSettings` and test if the settings have been applied correctly for all files in `$actualAclSettings?`**

Or do I have to check in `$expectedAclSettings` if the inheritance rules are preserved/protected or not, and depending on that, write a more complex test function that f.e. iterates over each path in `$actualAclSettings`, and checks based on the depth of the current file/folder and the inheritance settings that acl values should have been applied or not? Are there other approaches to test the acl values?

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a solution to compare the access control lists in a one-liner. The solution I used to compare the permissions and have the differences in a readable output, is to "hash" the permissions to a string, and recursively compare if the permissions. I will post the code I used below, maybe it helps somebody. If anyone has a better answer, feel free to post it, and I might update my code.

---

I used the following function `Compare-AccessRules` to compare access rules. It expects two objects of type "Access", these are returned from `Get-ACL`, f.e.:

```
$actualAclSettings = Get-Acl -Path $Path
$diff = Compare-AccessRules $actualAclSettings.Access $aexpectedAclSettings.Access
```

Here is the function:

```
function Compare-AccessRules {
  param (
    $ActualAccessRules,
    $ExpectedAccessRules
  )

  $actualAccessRuleStrings = foreach ($rule in $ActualAccessRules) {
    Convert-AccessRuleToString -AccessRule $rule
  }

  $expectedAccessRuleStrings = foreach ($rule in $ExpectedAccessRules) {
    Convert-AccessRuleToString -AccessRule $rule
  }

  return Compare-Object $expectedAccessRuleStrings $actualAccessRuleStrings
}
```

Inside this function, access rules are "hashed" with the `Convert-AccessRuleToString` function:

```
function Convert-AccessRuleToString {
  param(
    $AccessRule
  )

  return "IdentityReference : $($AccessRule.IdentityReference)`n" +
  "FileSystemRights  : $($AccessRule.FileSystemRights)`n" +
  "AccessControlType : $($AccessRule.AccessControlType)`n" +
  "IsInherited       : $($AccessRule.IsInherited)`n" + 
  "InheritanceFlags  : $($AccessRule.InheritanceFlags)`n" + 
  "PropagationFlags  : $($AccessRule.PropagationFlags)"
}
```